Quarkus keycloak admin client - how to get error reason
When using Quarkus with dependency quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive and invoking some method which does not return Response how do I get real reason why invocation has failed.
For example, if I invoke a method to update user:
UserResource userResource = fetchUserById(userId);
userResource.update(user);

I get the following exception stack trace:
ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /rest/v1/change-username failed, error id: d149a840-21bb-454f-97d9-50af5dc70359-1: org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.ClientWebApplicationException: Received: 'Server response is: 400' when invoking: Rest Client method: 'org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UserResource#update'
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext.unwrapException(RestClientRequestContext.java:195)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.handleException(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:331)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:175)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.RestClientRequestContext$1.lambda$execute$0(RestClientRequestContext.java:314)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:261)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:59)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.api.WebClientApplicationException: Server response is: 400
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSetResponseEntityRestHandler.handle(ClientSetResponseEntityRestHandler.java:32)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSetResponseEntityRestHandler.handle(ClientSetResponseEntityRestHandler.java:23)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.invokeHandler(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:231)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        ... 12 more

Trying to get entity from ClientWebApplicationException or WebApplicationException is giving me null.
But if I turn on the debug log for http request:
quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=request-response
quarkus.rest-client.logging.body-limit=1024
quarkus.log.category."org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.logging".level=DEBUG

I can see that http response has a body attached with a detail why request has failed. It's just that is is not mapped to an exception.
For example:
DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.cli.log.DefaultClientLogger] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Response: PUT https://keycloak-instance/admin/realms/realmName/users/da71b24c-eb88-4147-85a6-b172a093958f, Status[400 Bad Request], Headers[Date=Wed, 14 Aug 2024 20:35:50 GMT Content-Type=application/json Content-Length=92 Connection=keep-alive Referrer-Policy=no-referrer Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block], Body:
{"field":"username","errorMessage":"error-username-invalid-character","params":["username"]}

But if I create a user:
Response response = keycloak.realm("realmName").users().create(user);

I can read the entity from response which gives me reason why request have failed.
Does anyone know how to get response body when doing the user update?
I have tried implementing custom exception mappers but guess they don't work because it is handled by rest client.

Same problem here. Got no solution for this. There are no information provided via the exception and according to the documentation there are no options for this behavior: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-admin-client

@Tobi For now I have created RestClient which calls problematic keycloak endpoint: {keycloak-server}/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{id}. This way I can access response in a WebApplicationException when an error occurs. The problem seems to be custom implementation of a RestClient which is used in keycloak-admin-client extension: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/42577
